# how to hide collectionview when scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a table view and I have an collection above it, I need to hide this collection when scrolling is done in the table view (like a parallax header, only this collection is not in the header, but above the table view) what is the best way to do it? Please help, thank you.

I was looking for an answer here, but I didn't find it

Comment: You need to create a custom animation for this.
First off, you need to override the `scrollViewDidScroll` function and check if the user has scrolled down the number of pixels of your header height.
You can also create a nice animation if you deduct the header's height on scroll down until its height is zero.

Comment: If you've found code for a "parallax header" -- is there a reason you don't want to put the collection view in the table view header?

Comment: I'm just learning, so I probably don't know how to do it)

Comment: Your question is lacking detail (might be a good idea to review [ask]), but I'm guessing you want a horizontal scrolling collection view "above" the table view rows, that will be "pushed up off the screen" when scrolling the table? If so, you can either make the first row of your table a cell that contains the collection view, or put the collection view as the table view's `tableHeaderView`. Do some searching. If you try something and it's not working the way you want, edit your question with details and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yeah, u r right! Collection in tableHeaderView works fine, thanks!